# Range not found when using 'i' in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to get a very simple for loop to work where by I am adding to an array. Here is the function:

```
function findHotel() {
    var hotelNames = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= nameCells.length; i++) {
    hotelNames.push(ss.getRange(nameCells[i]).getValue());

  } Logger.log(hotelNames);
}

var nameCells = ["D25:D57"];
```

When I replace nameCells[i] with nameCells[1] for example, this works fine but obviously it just logs the value of D25 repeatedly. Why when I use the 'i' variable is it saying that it cannot find range?

Comment: JS arrays are zero based, don't you mean `i < nameCells.length` ? Can you please post more code in a [mcve]? And add the tags that show us what framework is producing `getRange().getValue()`

Comment: oh yes that was all it was! Very simple - changed to i < nameCells.length. Thanks !

Comment: Feel free to delete the question